# processing SQL query in 2 ways in php

Tags: php, sql, module

i wrote this pieceof code and i was and i was not able to process the query propery

```
$sql= "select * from users where email = ".$email." and pass = ".$password;
mysql_query($sql);
```

with this piece of code i was not able to login,

so later i changed it to

```
$sql= "select * from users where email = '$email' and pass = '$password'";
mysql_query($sql);
```

and then it worked fine.

can please some one explain what is the difference between the two ways

Comment: `echo` the two different queries and you'll find out! Most likely the first one produces a syntax error. Also, you are using a deprecated extension and are vulnerable to SQL injections, you should switch to PDO and prepared statements!

Comment: @MatteoTassinari it did not give me a syntax error.. the query was executed but but did not take the email address as it is. it skipped the characters before `@`

Comment: I see, anyway what I said in my comment still stands, I'd recommend changing the library used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one will work fine if you change it to:

```
$sql= "select * from users where email = '".$email."' and pass = '".$password."'";
mysqli_query($sql);
```

Comment: You are using a deprecated extension and are vulnerable to SQL injections, you should switch to PDO and prepared statements! @dhpratik no, quotes are not strictly necessary, only for string values, for numbers you could (and should) omit them.

Comment: That would work, but it still leaves you wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @Arjan I agree with you.But that is the valid method to pass a string through query.As far as SQL injection is concerned, you can always use `mysql_real_escape_string` and also some other mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Because Email and Password are string value you must have to single encode these value in sql query to execute properly so the query will be.

```
$sql= "select * from users where email = '".$email."' and pass = '".$password."'";
```

Comment: You are using a deprecated extension and are vulnerable to SQL injections, you should switch to PDO and prepared statements!